# iOS NSFetchedResultsController with UITableView Sections

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am wondering how to solve my problem.

I have:

- Entity A: Advertisers
- Entity B: Offers

I have some Advertisers with many offers (1:n relation) and Advertisers without offers. Finally, each offer has a price.

I have a UITableView with two sections
- Advertisers with offers
- Advertisers without offers

The difficulty comes now, the user can add a filter on the price. When a user set a max price at x, then the Advertisers without offers with a price less than x should not appear in the first section anymore.

First, I was thinking to set the sort descriptor and section name to a parameter "HasOffers". So first section would be hasOffers=1 and second section hasOffers=0. However when dealing with the offer price filter my solution does not fit anymore.

Someone has an idea?

Comment: Are you having `hasOffers` attributes in `Advertisers` entity with value 1 and 2?

Comment: Use two nsfetchedresultscontrollers; one for each section

Comment: @NiravD yep I do. When I create the entity instances, I set the attribute. It is then not transient as the core data concept allows only not transient attribute as sort descriptor.

Comment: @Paulw11 I already tried that, it's just that it's not that simple to handle modification  of context with this scheme. 
I mean, when the context notify that there is one more result in one of the two `nsfetechedresultcontroller`, how do you know if you need to add it in the first or second section of the tableview?

Comment: The fetchedresultcontroller instance is passed to the delegate method, so simply check which results controller it is and update the appropriate table section.